How does Flutter receives a POST request with the payload from a web application. My flutter app must consume/process the post
I am integrating a HTML based payment gateway to a flutter app. Once the payment is complete, the gateway will do a POST request tom my flutter appl with all transaction details. My flutter app must  consume/process and store these details.
How does flutter consume/receive POST request from the internet?

commenting because this doesn't answer your exact question but I believe you are headed in the wrong direction. Depending on what payment gateway your using, the general flow for something like this would be to provide the platform a 'redirect_url'. This redirect url would point them back to your flutter app with information contained in usually query strings that you can consume. If its a webhook the platform is emitting you would likely want to consume that on a server and not the flutter app itself.

Hi Braden, I am trying to use firebase realtime database, I have the notify_url (as stated in firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start) but I am failing to do a POST from my app. When I do a post to POST to json-placeholder site I get return code 401. This is my redirect url  There is something I am missing on the process to writing to the firebase database. Thanks for the comment.
